# Using multiple custom metrics adapters in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, prometheus, metrics, autoscaling

I am using GKE.

I have a cluster which is using stackdriver-adapter to get GCP metrics inside the cluster. I am using these metrics to create HPAs. This is working fine.

But now I need to create HPA on metrics which are provided by prometheus. I am trying to launch prometheus-adapter but it is failing because the API service has already been created by stackdriver-adapter. But if I delete the stackdriver my present HPAs will fail.

Can we have both prometheus-adapter and stackdriver-adpater running in the same cluster?

If no, I guess we need to send prometheus-metrics to stackdriver? But wouldn't that be slow?

Comment: Have a look at the documentation [Using Prometheus](https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/docs/solutions/gke/prometheus), you'll find there how to install Prometheus and get external metrics. After that, follow the documentation [Custom and external metrics for autoscaling workloads](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/custom-and-external-metrics) to configure HPA.

Answer (score 0):

As said in the comments:

> Have a look at the documentation [Using Prometheus](https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/docs/solutions/gke/prometheus), you'll find there how to install Prometheus and get external metrics. After that, follow the documentation [Custom and external metrics for autoscaling workloads](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/custom-and-external-metrics) to configure HPA.

---

You can configure a sidecar to the Prometheus server that will send the data from the Prometheus to the Stackdriver. From this point you will be able to use the Prometheus metrics as `External metrics` when configuring the `HPA`.

You will need to check following requirements before "installing" the collector:

> - You must be running a [compatible Prometheus server](https://github.com/Stackdriver/stackdriver-prometheus-sidecar) and have configured it to monitor the applications in your cluster. To learn how to install Prometheus on your cluster, refer to the [Prometheus Getting Started guide](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/getting_started/).
> - You must have configured your cluster to use Cloud Operations for GKE. For instructions, see [Installing Cloud Operations for GKE](https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/docs/solutions/gke/installing).
> - You must have the Kubernetes Engine Cluster Admin role for your cluster. For more information, see [GKE roles](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/iam#roles).
> - You must ensure that your service account has the proper permissions. For more information, see [Use Least Privilege Service Accounts for your Nodes](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/hardening-your-cluster#use_least_privilege_sa).
>
> -- *[Cloud.google.com: Stackdriver: Solutions: GKE: Prometheus: Before you begin](https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/docs/solutions/gke/prometheus#before_you_begin)*

For **testing** purposes of installing Prometheus and configuring the data transfer to the Stackdriver, I used the script from:

- *[Github.com: Stackdriver: Stackdriver-prometheus-sidecar](https://github.com/Stackdriver/stackdriver-prometheus-sidecar)*

Steps:

- download the repository:

  - `$ git clone https://github.com/Stackdriver/stackdriver-prometheus-sidecar.git`
- set the following environment variables (values are examples):

```sh
export KUBE_NAMESPACE="prometheus" 
export KUBE_CLUSTER="gke-prometheus"
export GCP_REGION="europe-west3-c"
export GCP_PROJECT="awesome-project-12345" 
export SIDECAR_IMAGE_TAG="0.8.0"
```

> `SIDECAR_IMAGE_TAG` can be found here:
>
> - *[Gcr.io: Stackdriver-prometheus: Stackdriver prometheus sidecar](http://gcr.io/stackdriver-prometheus/stackdriver-prometheus-sidecar)*

- run the script:

  - `kube/full/deploy.sh`

---

After successfully spawning Prometheus with a Stackdriver sidecar you should be able to see the metrics in the Cloud Console:

- `GCP Cloud Console` (Web UI) -> `Monitoring` -> `Metrics Explorer`

Example:

[image: METRICS]

From this point you can follow the guide for configuring `HPA` and set your `External metric` as the source for autoscaling your `Deployment`/`Statefulset`:

- *[Cloud.google.com: Kubernetes Engine: Tutorials: Autoscaling metrics](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/autoscaling-metrics)*

---

Additional resources:

- *[Kubernetes.io: Horizontal Pod Autoscaler](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/)*
- *[Cloud.google.com: Custom and external metrics for autoscaling workloads](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/custom-and-external-metrics)*